# Change scene in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i m using cocos2d and i want to change scene to replay the game when the player touches the end scene so that it starts the game again.
I just stuck to use touch event on  [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:2 scene:scene orientation:kOrientationLeftOver]];
Please Help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever send an existing, running scene to be replaced. Create a new instance of the same scene class if you want to restart the scene.